# python is giving me the wrong answer for how long it is until my next birthday

Tags: python

I'm having a problem with python about calculating how long it is until my next birthday. this is my code:

```
import datetime
currentDate=datetime.date.today()
userInput=raw_input('please enter your birthday(dd/mm/yyyy)')
birthday = datetime.datetime.strptime(userInput,'%d/%m/%Y').date()
days=birthday-currentDate
print(days)
```

the answer it gave me back was -6930.

when it gave me that answer I tried to break it down to parts like this:

```
import datetime
currentDate=datetime.date.today()
userInput=raw_input('please enter your birthday(dd/mm/yyyy)')
birthday = datetime.datetime.strptime(userInput,'%d/%m/%Y').date()
months =birthday.month-currentDate.month 
days = birthday.day-currentDate.day
print('your next birthday is in ' +str(months) +' months and '+ str(days) + 'days' )
```

and then it was ok for an input that the month was equal or bigger than the current month, so when I typed as an input:18/09/1996 it gave the answer "your next birthday is in 2 months and 9 days"  but if the month on the input was smaller than the current month like:18/05/1996 the answer it gave me back was"tour birthday is in -2 months and 9 days"

hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the date of your *next* birthday, getting the difference between the month and the day of the month is not enough.

First, start by transposing the birthday to this year; you may want to handle leap years:

```
birthday = datetime.datetime.strptime(userInput, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
today = datetime.date.today()
try:
    next_birthday = birthday.replace(year=today.year)
except ValueError:
    # oops, not a leapyear this year, no february 29th; use the day before
    next_birthday = birthday.replace(day=28, year=today.year)

if next_birthday < today:  # already passed this year, pick next year
    try:
        next_birthday = birthday.replace(year=today.year + 1)
    except ValueError:
        # oops, not a leapyear next year, no february 29th, use the day before
        next_birthday = birthday.replace(day=28, year=today.year + 1)

difference = next_birthday - today
months, days = divmod(difference.days, 30)  # assume 30 days per month
print 'Your birthday is in about {} months and {} days'.format(months, days)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do the following?:

If it is greater than the month/day of your birthday in the current year, then subtract the current date from your birthday NEXT year.

Otherwise, you haven't hit your birthday for this year, so subtract the current date from THIS year's birthday.

Comment: thanks a lot! I like the fact you just gave me a hint about what is needed to be done instead of the whole code, I succeeded :)

Comment: Great job! Glad I could help.